# Koa - cannot increase default request timeout

Tags: node.js, koa

I need help increasing the 2 min default request timeout in a Koa server.
I have a long task operation that is taking a few minutes. When it is finished I'm sending a response back. The problem is that the connection is automatically closed after a timeout of 2 min which is node js default.

I tried everything in google.
tried using all kind of third party npm modules.

tried ctx.request.socket.setTimeout(0)

I am out of ideas and need help.

I am executing my requests to the server using postmen with infinite timeout.

**Update** - This is a code snipped of something im trying to do:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()
const PORT = 7555
const server = app.listen(PORT)

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.req.setTimeout(0);
    await next();
});


app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    const wait = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve()
            }, 1000 * 60 * 5)

        })
    }
    await wait()
    console.log("settimeout finished", new Date())
    ctx.response.body = { success: "true", date: new Date() }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this one ... worked fine:

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()
const PORT = 7555
const server = app.listen(PORT);

server.setTimeout(0); // <-- this should do the trick ...

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log("request started", new Date())
    const wait = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve()
            }, 1000 * 60 * 5)

        })
    }
    await wait()
    console.log("settimeout finished", new Date())
    ctx.response.body = { success: "true", date: new Date() }
})
```

Be sure that - if `apache` or `nginx` is involved in your production system to also modify their configurations (here I increased it to 500 seconds).

**For NGINX (proxy)**

```
vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add following in `http{..}` section

(see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)

```
http {
    #...
        proxy_read_timeout 500s;
        proxy_send_timeout 500s;
    #...
}
```

**For Apache**

```
vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
```

Search for TimeOut

```
# ...
TimeOut 500
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a middleware early on your app like this:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.req.setTimeout(0);
    await next();
});
```

It seems koa keeps the [120s timeout default from http_server.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.x/lib/_http_server.js#L302)

So, you could try to hack into it, but this middleware should do the trick.

You could also try this:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT); // This returns the https_server instance

server.setTimeout(600000)
```

You can see relevant info [here](https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/766)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work for me. I have added a code snppet to my question

Comment: Could you check if setting the timeout on the https_server instance helps?

Comment: It works in a dummy server i made but for some reason it doesnt work in my main server where im trying to implement this.

Comment: In my answer (see above) I added also configuration options for nginx and apache - in case that they are involved in your production system...